# Installing geoPHP with Geos on Drupal 7

Tags: php, drupal-7, centos6, geos

I installed geophp Module in my drupal 7 installation.
Also installed Geos in my server following these steps 
http://duntuk.com/how-install-geos-centos
I enabled geophp module in drupal, everything goes right, but when I go to the status report, It says this 
"GeoPHP library installed and OK. However, GEOS is was not found. While not required, you will see performance improvements if you install the GEOS PHP extension. See the following link for more information.https://github.com/phayes/geoPHP/wiki/GEOS"

The geos.so file is in the right folder "/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626", also the php.ini has the right "extension_dir", I restarted the server, but it in the status page keeps saying the legend that GEOS was not found.
On terminal when I type "geos-config --version" it says:
3.4.2
So I guess Geos got installed correctly.
I am using php version 5.3.26, on centos 6.5.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Got resolved!

On this step, 
"create a /etc/php.d/geos.ini file with the following content:

; GEOS extension
extension=geos.so"

I also modified the php.ini that is located on "/usr/local/lib", and "/usr/local/lib/php"
adding on those file the same line 
"extension=geos.so"
And be sure that "extension_dir" is the right one on both, I am not sure if these are extra steps or not necesary but it worked magically for me.

Hope it helps some one else.